# how can I deploy a laravel project on website for live like a traditional php project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I tried to deploy my laravel project on website but it doesn't get the link of my page according to my route file when I access it from public folder.

I run my project on localhost by php artisan command line.

Comment: are you adding the project on your server using a repository like github?

Comment: yes, I add my project using a github repository

Comment: on the terminal on your host server try to run sudo php artisan and see whether is displays the list of commands

Comment: If you did a sudo git clone to get the project on the server the vendor was not installed. You need to do composer update to ensure that composer installs the laravel vendor for you....this should solve your problem

Comment: i was trying a free hosting site. There is no command line terminal. It's a traditional php hosting server.

Comment: http://driesvints.com/blog/laravel-4-on-a-shared-host

Comment: There is also a nearly perfect workflow using laravel forge and hosting platforms like digitalocean. Everytime you update your project on github, forge sets up your project on digitalocean. Thats the best solution for me and works like charm.

Comment: Have you confirmed your .htaccess is working correctly with any URL Re-Writes?